# Add virtualenv name to prompt when using pew

Tags: bash, virtualenv

I am using [`pew`](https://github.com/berdario/pew) to manage virtual environments on macOS El Capitan. I would like to get some indication of the virtualenv I am in once I activate one. According to [the docs](https://github.com/berdario/pew#display-the-environment-name-in-the-terminal-prompt), this behavior should be available out of the box, but if it is not, that you can configure it by adding `source $(pew shell_config)` to your `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`. I have added this, but it has no affect.

To create a minimal example, I have removed everything from my `.bash_profile` except for `source $(pew shell_config)`. When I run the `pew workon` command, my prompt does change, but it simply changes to `bash-3.2$`, with no indication of the virtual environment.

How can I update my `.bash_profile` so that `pew workon` will cause the name of the virtual environment to be displayed in the prompt?

It is my understanding that the prompt that is setup when you switch to a virtualenv is set in `shell_config/init.bash`. In my case, this file looks like this:

```
source "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"/complete.bash

PS1="\[\033[01;34m\]\$(basename '$VIRTUAL_ENV')\[\e[0m\]$PS1"
```

It looks like this should give me the behavior that I want, but it does not seem to be working, and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Make a .bashrc in your ~ directory and paste in "source $(pew shell_config)"

I had this issue as well and discovered that pew looks for .bashrc, not .bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20 paste this to the end of .bashrc

```
# Pew
source "$(~/.local/bin/pew shell_config)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem lies in quoting:

```
PS1="\[\033[01;34m\]\$(basename '$VIRTUAL_ENV')\[\e[0m\]$PS1"
```

will expand `$VIRTUAL_ENV` *only* when it is called the first time and will define a prompt which is unresponsive to subsequent changes of `$VIRTUAL_ENV`. Try this:

```
PS1='\[\e[01;34m\]$(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV")\[\e[0m\]'"$PS1"
```